# Server hangs when client disconnects

Tags: java, android

i am creating a multiple-client/server app whenever any client disconnects from
my server it just hangs.
how can i set any condition that will tell me print some message whenever
any client disconnects from the server
here is my server code

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("server starting.......");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Ready to accept.......");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println(" client Connected with ip address =" +socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("catch block");

            }

        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {

            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {


        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hangs how?  It stops accepting any new connections, or just the CommunicationThread gets stuck?

Comment: i have a textview to which i set all messages that are received from clients. but whenever any client diconnectes textview displays client says:null and this goes on in loop and finally my app crashes

Comment: Yeah just listen on some port to receive a string, If you receive something , stop server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you mean disconnect because the conversation was over (ie: everything completed successfully) or the disconnect is because of some network problems (or the client canceled the request).

If it's the first case, then it's easy: the protocol you are using (your own, or http, or whatever) is in charge of defining how to determine that a conversation was over. If that situation arises, then you just close the socket.

If it's the second case, then you'd have to have an algorithm in place to determine whether or not the connection must be closed. For instance, by implementing a timeout, or a slow-read threshold. Take a look at the [Socket's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) for instructions on how to set a timeout.

It's also worth noting that it's fine to create your own servers when you want to practice or learn something, but you'd be better off using an existing solution, like vert.x or a slimmed down version of Wildfly, for instance. The overhead of such servers is very low, nowadays, while still providing very robust networking capabilities.

Comment: server hangs when client disconnects because of network problems.how to handle that exactly? i have a textview to which i am setting all messages that are receive from client. but when any client disconnects textview displays "null" continuously in loop and finally crashes

Comment: Well, both your client and your server have to handle a network connectivity issue situation. As I mentioned, the Socket class provides a timeout, of which you can handle this case. But there are a lot more cases to think about than just this one, hence my recommendation for a real server implementation.